# Play video on Vaadin

Tags: java, youtube, vaadin

I'm trying to play a video of YouTube using Embedded.

I have the following code:

```
    Embedded e = new Embedded(null, new ExternalResource("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AldZqeM0vjQ"));
    e.setMimeType("application/x-shockwave-flash");
    e.setParameter("allowFullScreen", "true");
    e.setWidth("800px");
    e.setHeight("480px");
```

But it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess would that that doesn’t match with the way you should embed YouTube videos. That’s at least a normal YouTube address for watching as a normal user, and not an embedding url.

I read YouTube instructions, https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/171780?hl=en, and they seem to recommend iframe embedding (not flash embedding) with a url like https://www.youtube.com/embed/AldZqeM0vjQ (not “watch”)